# ¿Como combinar estas celdas en html?

Tags: html

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
<div class="card data-table nueva-table">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="nuevo-td" style="font-size: 11px;">Nombre</thd>
                        <th class="nuevo-td" style="font-size: 11px;">Individual</th>
                        <td class="label-cell nuevo-th" style="font-size: 11px;">Red</th>
                        <th class="label-cell nuevo-th" style="font-size: 11px;">Titulo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="listado_volumen_negocio" class="listado_volumen_negocio">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Visualmente es de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en las celdas Individual y red se debe ver de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muy agradecido.

Comment: no entiendo como deseas que quede asi? si nisiquiera coinciden los nombres?

Comment: Coincido con Bryro, de donde sale el nombre Red Directa por ejemplo

Comment: Seria una nueva celda, en la parte superior. Es cierto, me falto agregar la palabra "Directa" en  la imagen anterior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que deseas saber es como hacer uso de `rowspan` y `colspan` de html, te dejo un ejemplo simple:

```html
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='2'>
      rowspan 2
    </td>
    <td colspan='2'>
      colspan 2
    </td>
    <td rowspan='2'>
      rowspan 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>celda normal</td>
    <td>celda normal</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Espero que el pequeño ejemplo te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad que debes usar en la fila y celda superior es "colspan" e indicar la cantidad de columnas que unirá.

```
<table border=1>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">a</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>a</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Colspan

```
<div class="card data-table nueva-table">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th colspan="2" style="font-size: 11px;">Volumen de Negocio</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="nuevo-td" style="font-size: 11px;">Nombre</th>
            <th class="nuevo-td" style="font-size: 11px;">Individual</th>
            <td class="label-cell nuevo-th" style="font-size: 11px;">Red</th>
            <th class="label-cell nuevo-th" style="font-size: 11px;">Titulo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="listado_volumen_negocio" class="listado_volumen_negocio">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Tu respuesta fue incluida en la lista de revisión de baja calidad, y esto es debido a que tiene solamente código. Te recomiendo incluir siempre una explicación, aunque sea breve, de cuál es el problema que el OP tiene en su código de la pregunta y/o cómo tu solución resuelve ese problema. Un saludo.